# Benchmarks for custom database

Tags: nosql, performance, benchmark, performance-testing

I am looking for an open source benchmark tool that can easily be extended to custom databases. The reason is I have created a new NoSQL DBMS (called Borrego) that support both JSON queries like MongoDB and DB2 JSON, and generic SQL statements via a JDBC driver. I would like to run some performance tests that I can compare with other existing databases.
Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found YCSB, the Yahoo Cloud System Benchmark:
https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB

It has bindings for many DBMSs, including jdbc and rest interfaces, so it seems to have exactly what I needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is [mgbench](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/tree/master/tests/mgbench) that is part of Memgraph. In the README file, you can see the details of the methodology. Maybe it can be extended to suit your needs?

There is a result for comparison of two graph databases, Memgraph and Neo4j, at the [blog post](https://memgraph.com/blog/memgraph-vs-neo4j-performance-benchmark-comparison).